Calculations for mirror size positioned near the eye to observe a sideway object
I have this quick sketch I've just created for an object sitting to the left of an observer (an eye for simplicity) which is to be observed only through a tilted mirror.

I would like to know how to calculate the needed dimensions of this mirror so that it fully reflects the object given its dimensions. I would assume the size of the mirror is very much bound to the distance to the eye as well.
I would appreciate some pointers or clarification for the needed formulae.
PS: While searching the Internet, I understood that calculating the angular size using arctan(size/distance) or its approximation for small distances size/distance is needed, but I am still not sure how to conclude the dimensions of the needed mirror.

Consider the total distance $L$ a ray must travel between the object and your eye. This is the sum of the distance $l$ between your eye and the mirror and the distance between the mirror and the object. Then the object of dimension $d$ will appear in the mirror to be of angular size $\delta=2\arctan\frac{d}{2L}$. For the object to be completely visible in the mirror, it must have an angular size at least as large and therefore a dimension $D$ given:
$$\begin{align*}\delta&=2\arctan\frac{D}{2l}\\
\implies D&=2l\tan\frac{\delta}{2}\\&=2l\tan\left(\arctan\frac{d}{2L}\right)\\&=\frac{ld}{L}\end{align*}$$
This is the length of the mirror as projected onto the plane perpendicular to the line connecting it with the viewer. For the "vertical" dimension (parallel to the axis of rotation of the mirror) this corresponds with the physical size of the mirror. For the "horizontal" dimension, the mirror needs to be made larger by a factor $\sec\theta$ for a mirror at an angle $\theta$ from face-on in order to subtend the same angle from the viewer's perspective.

Newtonian telescopes (the exact situation described in the OP) have elliptical mirrors.  Shouldn't the mirror in this case have two dimensions, with the longer one root2 times the length in your solution?

@DJohnM Indeed, this is the dimension as projected onto the plane perpendicular to the line connecting the viewer and the mirror. To be even more general the factor is $\sec\theta$ for an arbitrary mirror angle. I will amend my answer
